# First time working with mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm trying to retrofit a project of mine to use real_escape_string. I've read the documentation, tutorials, and stackoverflow related questions, and it seems like I'm doing it correctly, but obviously something is wrong. I'm very confident it's the real_escape_string itself, since when I comment that out, everything works as it did. I'm going for the object oriented way.

Here's my connect.

```
$con= new mysqli("localhost","root","","venue");
```

Here's me escaping the string.

```
$message = $_POST['text'];
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $message);
```

Here's my query

```
        $operation = "INSERT INTO
            chat(user, message)
        VALUES('". $_SESSION['name'] ."', '$message')"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $operation);
```

I've tried changing the $message in the query to '". $message .'". I've tried changing how I call the query as well. I've tried dozens of combinations, and read more than enough. I'm still missing something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the olny difference from mysql_* is the connection parameter.

Comment: If you're doing the retrofit anyway, consider moving to parameterised queries, or even better, an ORM. `m_r_e_s` still [has problems](http://hacktutorials.tumblr.com/post/63371180086/sql-injecting-through-mysql-real-escape-string) and even though it makes things much harder, it's still not secure. Since you're doing the rewrite anyway, it's worth going all the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***mysqli_real_escape_string***](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) takes two parameters, you forgot to put the connection to your databse and also delete the `$` before mysqli_real_escape_string because it's a mysqli function not a variable.

```
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $message);
```

You've got and extra semi-colon. Just delete it

```
$operation = "INSERT INTO
                chat(user, message)
            VALUES('". $_SESSION['name'] ."', '$message')";
```

Comment: Still not working. Also, doesn't queries need a semi-colon at the end sent to the database. I'll update my original post to reflect current code

Comment: @Goose try saving your session_name in a variable $name then try this VALUES('$name', '$message')";

Comment: Whoa, was not expecting that to work. Why was that the issue? The name was working when I wasn't escaping the message. Do I have to escape every variable or none of them for a query to work? What's the explination?

Comment: @Goose does that solve the problem? :) The query cannot read that kind of concatenation so that's why you save it to a variable. There is another way by using '{$_SESSION['name']}'